# Trouble connecting to inernet

Tags: networking

I can't ping to anything outside of my local network and I think it has to do with my connection not getting a global scope, the ifconfig command returns this:

```
eth0  Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr bc:5f:f4:99:a0:e9  
      inet6 addr: fe80::be5f:f4ff:fe99:a0e9/64 Scope:Link
      UP BROADCAST RUNNING PROMISC MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
      RX packets:121614 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
      TX packets:186744 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
      collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000 
      RX bytes:9647809 (9.6 MB)  TX bytes:230285614 (230.2 MB)
```

any ideas on what might be going on?

Answer (score 0):

You don't have an ipv4 address, your ipv6 address is only applicable inside your broadcast domain.. its non-routable.

[Relevant Wiki](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Link-local_address)

Comment: So basically his ipv4 is disabled, is that what you mean?